# Comparing several line functions for finding the minimum values!

Tags: analysis, functions

i am trying to find a method or an equation for the following problem.

There are some line equastions. 
$$y_i=a_i+bx_i $$
For example six such equtions (lines) How can be found the following context:

The value is pretermined. All y=a+bx equations and the xi and yi values are given. The min x should be found and should be as small as possible!

$$(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)+(x_3,y_3)+(x_4,y_4)+(x_5,y_5)+(x_6,y_6) = (min x, value)$$

Is it possible to solve such a problem and how?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Before posting questions, check out the guide on MathJax to write better equations in your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This does not really make sense without restrictions. One can choose each $x_i$ to be arbitrary small (among negative numbers) and consider the corresponding $y_i=a_i+bx_i$. If you require the $x_i$ to be non negative, then simply take all of them equal $0$.

Comment: If all of the $x$ and $y$ values are given, then what is there to do?

Comment: I can not take them all 0, because the value is pretermined, for example 10. The values all not negative. The x and y values are given as the equation y=a+bx and not as seperate values.